# Reading JSON data from the net (Twitter)

Tags: java, android, json, twitter, inputstream

I found this great tutorial on how to use JSON to retrieve Twitter updates, and post it in a TextView:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-andbene1/

I've followed this tutorial step by step, so my code is the same.

In the method `examineJSONFile()`, we have this line:

`InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jsontwitter);`

This file is downloaded directly from the Twitter website, as mentioned in the second paragraph of http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-andbene1/#aotf.

All this is great, except for one thing: it's absolutely no use that one has to download the Twitter updates (tweets) and then build the app using this as a raw file. It should be possible to download this JSON file at runtime, and then show the tweets in the TextView afterwards.

I have tried to create the `InputStream` in another way, like this:

```
String url = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/bbcnews.json";
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
try
{
    String line = null;

    while ((line = br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append('\n');                
    }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
String jsontext = new String(sb.toString());
```

But it seems this line: `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));` throws an exception.

Any help please?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the details of the exception which is thrown (at least the first line with the type of the exception and the message string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the INTERNET permission. Look at the logs and it would be clear what exactly is the problem.